# Name for complex number with nonzero imaginary component

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology

Complex numbers include all real numbers. Is there a name for the subset of complex numbers which does not include any real numbers (i.e. where the imaginary component is nonzero)?

Comment: complex and non-real ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: non-real.  Universally used and understood.  Non-trivially complex or realized complex could be used but are probably confusing and contextual.  Non-real is perfectly fine.

Comment: From wiki "A real number $a$ can be regarded as a complex number $a + 0i$, whose imaginary part is $0$. A purely imaginary number $bi$ is a complex number $0 + bi$, whose real part is $0$." A complex number where the real part is zero is a (purely) imaginary number. So an imaginary number is just a scaling of $i$. Is there a term for complex numbers with a non-zero imaginary part (this includes purely imaginary complex numbers and complex numbers with both a nonzero real and imaginary part). Maybe `non-reals`. Also do we have keep saying 'purely' imaginary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally there isn't any name for them (as far as I'm aware). You could just use "non-real" as long as the context is assumed to be in the complex plane, rather than say the hyper complex numbers. You could also just use the symbol $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Strictly imaginary would mean 0 + bi and not include a + bi in general.  "Non-real complex" or "complex and non-real" is clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Ahh yes good point, thanks! I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Many times numbers of the form $a+bi$ when $a=0$ (so just $bi$) are called purely imaginary.

Comment: But that doesn't take into account a+bi $a \ne 0$.

Comment: It also fails to exclude $0.$

Comment: @coffeemath Zero is considered both a real number and an imaginary number.